# Why were the IDF removed from Dust2, and why was Dust2 removed from the Active Duty map pool?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-2

I noticed after the 2023 October 7 attack by Hamas on Israel:

1. In *CS2*/*CSGO*, the IDF (Israeli Defense Forces) were removed in Dust2.
2. And ultimately, Dust2 the most popular map ever, was removed from the Active Duty map pool.

What are the stated reasons for these, and what were the exact dates of each?

Answer (score 1):

The IDF being removed maybe; but we will never know. Valve has just quietly removed them 6 months ago.

But for D2 being removed from the map pool, that has nothing to do with it. Valve does add and remove maps from the 'active map pool' every once in a while just to keep the game fresh and mostly the esport fresh. You can see the history here. https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/12w6148/history_of_the_map_pool_at_majors_mirage_is_the/

Usually they will take out a map when they feel its the most solved of the 7 and replace it with a new/reworked map.

Comment: THANK YOU. 1 - what date exactly was it removed please? 2 - ok thanks for putting in the context of my mere 2018Dec - 2022Jan perspective. but idk really 2023? probably the expected there was going to be a thing soon. can you dispute by saying for the other maps the IRL CT side weren't engaging in huge conflict or something?